# why does `sum` on a Matrix return Matrix, not Vector?

Tags: julia

If I do

```
mat = rand(8,8)
sum(mat, 1)
```

the return type is a Matrix with a single row, whereas `sum(mat, 2)` gives a Matrix with a single column. This surprises me, as singleton dimensions are generally dropped in 0.5, so I would expect the return type of both operations would be a Vector. Why is the singleton dimension not dropped here?

I might expect this was in order to preserve the orientation (e.g. `sum(mat, 1)` is a row Vector), but the behaviour is the same on 0.6, which has explicit 1-d RowVectors, so this does not appear to be an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, reductions like `sum` preserve the dimensionality of the array.  This is intentional as it enables broadcasting the result back across the original array.  This means that you can, for example, normalize the columns of an array with `./`:

```
julia> A = rand(1:100, 4, 3)
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 94  50  32
 46  15  78
 34  29  41
 79  22  58

julia> A ./ sum(A, 1)
4×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.371542  0.431034  0.15311
 0.181818  0.12931   0.373206
 0.134387  0.25      0.196172
 0.312253  0.189655  0.277512
```

While the two-dimensional case might be able to be handled by `RowVector`s, that approach does not generalize to higher dimensions.

That said, there are other cases where dropping dimensions would [be similarly useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580002/176071).  This is an [open design question on the issue tracker](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16606).

Comment: Nice, thanks! I did think about the broadcast, but not that it wouldn't generalize to higher dimensions. I see the issue, so, thanks!
This came up because I am defining functions on row and column sums of matrices, and it seems natural to define the input arguments as `Vector`s, but that means I have to call, e.g. `myfunc(vec(sum(mat,1)))`, which looks clumsy. But allowing the arguments to be Matrices seems like it could cause problems. I guess I can address this with dispatch, though.

Comment: There's often no need to restrict argument types so strictly.  Instead of `Vector`, you could almost certainly use `AbstractVector` — that'll include views and reshaped vectors and many other custom vector types.  And it's common to go even wider than that to all dimensionalities and maybe even to `Any`.  Sure, passing something nonsensical might error a little later than you might otherwise like, but it enables someone to pass you something that [looks like a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Julia) and it would still quack just fine.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am on board with that it is not normally necessary to restrict types in function arguments (and important inside types), and I like the principle! Also, I did use AbstractVector (sorry for the unclarity). In this case, though, a row matrix and a column matrix have different behavior from a Vector (e.g. when passed to a function such as `size`), so might it not lead to unexpected bugs if I ignored the dimensionality?
In the end I did something along `f(x::AbstractMatrix) = f(vec(x)); f(x::AbstractVector)...`